# Are multiple location blocks faster than multiple regex rewrites in a single block?

Tags: nginx, performance

In the [config pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites) of the nginx docs, it's mentioned that regex should be kept simple. Well, in my case I can avoid it altogether and I wonder if that's going to matter in terms of performance.

I want to serve all static files, route other requests to a single `index.php` file, and block access to files in a few folders by passing them to that same `index.php` file, which then renders a 404 page.

I can do this:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/foo/(.*) /index.php last;
    rewrite ^/bar/(.*) /index.php last;
    rewrite ^/baz/(.*) /index.php last;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

...or this:

```
location /foo/ {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}

location /bar/ {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}

location /baz/ {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

In the first example, nginx **always** has to evaluate the 3 regex patterns. In the second example, it only has to evaluate one at most, and it's a simpler one. My theory is that the second config will be faster. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the difference in performance is quite minimal, and you would require a long test run for each case to see which one performs the best.

Here are some alternatives how to implement your requirements:

**No capture in statements**

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/foo/ /index.php last;
    rewrite ^/bar/ /index.php last;
    rewrite ^/baz/ /index.php last;
}
```

There is no need to use the capture group in the regex, since the value isn't used for anything.

**One regular expression to match all possibilities**

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(?:foo|bar|baz) /index.php last;
}
```

This regex combines the three alternatives into a single expression. The `?:` prevents the regular expression capture, which would otherwise happen when parentheses are used.

**Match all parts in regular expression in `location`.**

```
location ~ ^/(?:foo|bar|baz) {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```

**Ignore regular expression match with location prefix match**

```
location ^~ /foo/ {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}

location ^~ /bar/ {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}

location ^~ /baz/ {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

You should measure the performance between these options to see which is fastest. The speed might also be affected by other things in the configuration.

These alternatives do work a bit different with respect to other configuration, so you need to make sure that other parts of the app work correctly.